# application/octet-stream Content Type get null request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

There is a problem in `application/octet-stream` in sending request to node.js server.
Request body is empty `{}` in server.

#### Question

Why the server take empty request body? and why it lost ?

#### Fetch Request

```
async function postData(url = '', data) {
                        console.log('data', data);
                        const response = await fetch(url, {
                            method: 'POST',
                            mode: 'cors',
                            cache: 'no-cache',
                            credentials: 'same-origin',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                                'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'
                            },
                            redirect: 'follow',
                            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
                            body: data
                        });
                        return response; //.arrayBuffer();
                    }

                    postData('http://localhost:3600/buffer', arrU8)
                        .then(data => {
                            console.log(data);
                        });
```

`arrU8` is an `Uint8Array` by length : 33411528

#### Node.js post api

Express.js is used as standard library.
This api is very simple and I want just return back the request body as response without any processing on body.

```
exports.buffer = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    res.status(201).send(req.body);
};
```

#### Response

```
{}
```

Comment: You've included lots of detail on the wrong side of the connection. :-) We need to know the details of the *server* side. What is `resive`? (And did you mean `receive`?) What is calling it? Something in the Node.js standard library? Express.js? Something else? WIth Express.js, for instance, you [have to use middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) to read and parse the body. How are you doing that (if using Express.js)?

Comment: Side note: There is no `conte` property in the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) options object.

Comment: Assuming the "Response" section is showing the result of the `console.log` in your client-side code: You're logging a `Response` object, which seems odd. Normally you'd check `ok` and then read the response body with a method like the commented-out `arrayBuffer` in your code (or `json` or `text`, etc.).

Comment: What is ```conte``` ? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I don't know. It's in your code, the fifth property you're providing as the second argument to `fetch`.

Comment: I don't used any middleware in this section, I want just return back the same request body as response without any processing. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: OK :) It was a misspelling @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Thanks a lot of your attention @T.J.Crowder , I now will work on middleware. Hoping this issue will be resolved

Answer (score 3):

After inspecting the body-parser module, you find that there are these scripts:

```
json.js
raw.js
text.js
urlencoded.js
```

They likely each match up to specific MIME-types. For application/octet-stream, you'd need to make use of raw.js. To do so, when initializing your express app, you should write:

```
app.use(require("body-parser").raw());
```

This will initialize the middleware that sets that req.body attribute, when the content-type is "application/octet-stream". Since req.body does not exist initially in the req object, it needs to be set by something. That something tends to be some function(s) in the middleware, or if you know, you could do it yourself (that implies looking at the request headers and parsing the stream).

To get direct access to the bytes stream of the request (and by inspecting the module's source code), you find that there's a stream being read from:

```
let stream = zlib.createInflate();
req.pipe(stream);
```

or

```
let stream = zlib.createGunzip();
req.pipe(stream);
```

I must say that I myself do not understand the details of the stream or the req object further than this.

Answer (score 2):

You've clarified that you're using Express.js and aren't using any middleware.

You have to use middleware to get `req.body` populated in Express.js. From [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body):

> **`req.body`**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. **By default, it is `undefined`**, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as `express.json()` or `express.urlencoded()`.

*(my emphasis)*

So your code is basically doing `.send(undefined)`.

If you don't want to use middleware for some reason, the Express.js `Request` is an augmented version of Node.js's built-in [`IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage), so you can use those methods to read the data as (say) a `Buffer` or similar if you want.